# Not able to push comment object to an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am not able to post a comment into the comments section of a blog page:

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", function(req,res){

    //lookup for the campground ID
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err,campground){

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }else{
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err,comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The error I am getting is

```
> (node:9300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: comments: Cast to
> [undefined] failed for value
> "[{"_id":"5a6f2d7a1463e52454e367f4","text":"I wish I witness this
> serenity with my naked eyes","author":"shaykoo","__v":0}]" at path
> "comments" { comments:     [ { _id: 5a6f2d7a1463e52454e367f4,
>        text: 'I wish I witness this serenity with my naked eyes',
>        author: 'shaykoo',
>        __v: 0 } ],   _id: 5a6f2d791463e52454e367f0,   name: 'Indian camps',   image:
> 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8225/8524305204_43934a319d.jpg',  
> desc: 'Here is the romanian campground',   __v: 1 }
```

Campground Schema

```
var mongoose= require("mongoose");
```

var campgroundSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

```
name: String,
image: String,
desc:String,
comments: [
    {
        type :mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
        ref:"Comment"                         //"Comment is the Model name"
    }

    ]
```

});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Campground",campgroundSchema);

comment schema

```
var mongoose= require("mongoose");
```

var commentSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

```
text: String,
author: String
```

});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Comment",commentSchema);  // here Comment is the singular name of the model

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us the schema definitions for both `Campground` and `Comment` models?

Comment: Please note that mongoose query is a Promise.

Comment: the problem is with the schema, edit your question to include the schema code (it's trying to cast your object to and undefined. so the schema is making mongoose think it should expect undefined)